# JQuery get select element inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table element which has a select element in its td. The table id (table1 in the example) can keep changing. So, how can I fetch the selected option using table ID in JQuery?

```
    <table class="indexViews" id = "table1">
   <tr>
    <td align="center", width="10%" valign="middle"></td>
    <td align="center", width="70%" valign="middle">
        <select  id="indexViewsList" class="indexViewsListWnd" onChange="switchIndexView(this)">
            <option id="0" value="0" selected="selected">Index Quick View</option>
            <option id="1" value="1">Identifier View</option>
            <option id="2" value="2">Commodity</option>
        </select></td>
    <td align="right", width="10%" valign="middle"><input class="searchIcon" type="image" src="../../images/downloadIcon.gif" alt="Submit" onClick="downloadIndexFile()"></input></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do *both* `id`s keep changing, or just the `table` element's? What *makes* them change (and honestly, changing an `id` doesn't make a lot of sense, really)?

Comment: First, why does the table id keep changing, and second does the table ID HAVE to keep changing?

Comment: Only the table ID keeps changing. This is because I have multiple windows which have this table. I append this table element to each window while creating them. I assign a unique table ID to each window while appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
var selectedValue= $(".indexViews .indexViewsListWnd").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why your id keep changing. But maybe you will want to iterate through your table using jquery selector on class name.

```
var lstIndexView = $(".indexViews .indexViewsListWnd");
```

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. I have explained the reason for Table ID changing in my previous comment. It is a requirement and I don't understand why has this question be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this selector in jQuery `$('table[id^="table"]')`

[Jquery - "Attribute starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get it using table id.

```
$('#table1 #indexViewsList').val();
```

But better you get this select directly:

```
$('#indexViewsList').val();
```